# SQL query to insert data into a table containing foreign key in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, select, sql-insert

This is the code which contains an add button which when clicked should add the data from textboxes to the bill table here `crid`, `crname`, `cid`, `cname` and `truckid` are foreign keys.

When the add button is clicked the data is not added inside the table and it shows no error hence I'm not really sure for what is causing this.

```cs
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI;
    
namespace project
{
    public partial class bill : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }

        //add
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (BillCheck())
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage",
                    "alert('This bill already exists. Please generate a new bill.')", true);
            }
            else
            {
                addNewBill();
            }
        }

        //user defined function
        void addNewBill()
        {
            if (TextBox1.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage",
                    "alert(GR no cannot be blank')", true);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                        "insert into bill (GRNo,Date,from,to,crid,crname,cid,cname,package," +
                        "description,HSNcode,privatemark,invoiceno,value,truckid,paymentmode,actual,charged,amount)" +
                        " (@GRNo,@Date,@from,@to,(select crid from Consignor where crid='" + TextBox4.Text.Trim() +
                        "';)," +
                        "(select crname from Consignor where crname='" + TextBox5.Text.Trim() + "';)," +
                        "(select cid from Consignee where cid='" + TextBox8.Text.Trim() + "';)," +
                        "(select cname from Consignee where cname='" + TextBox9.Text.Trim() +
                        "';),@package,@description,@HSNcode,@privatemark," +
                        "@invoiceno,@value,@paymentmode,@actual,@charged,@amount);", con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GRNo", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", TextBox7.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", TextBox3.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@crid", TextBox4.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@crname", TextBox5.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", TextBox8.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cname", TextBox9.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@package", TextBox6.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", TextBox10.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HSNcode", TextBox11.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@privatemark", TextBox12.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoiceno", TextBox13.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", TextBox14.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@truckid", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paymentmode", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@actual", TextBox21.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@charged", TextBox22.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", TextBox23.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage",
                        "alert('New Bill added Successfully!')", true);
                    clearForm();
                    GridView2.DataBind();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage",
                        "alert('" + ex.Message + "')", true);
                }
            }
        }

        public bool BillCheck()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from bill where GRNo='" + TextBox1.Text.Trim() + "';", con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count >= 1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage",
                    "alert('" + ex.Message + "')", true);
                return false;
            }
        }

        void clearForm()
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "";
            TextBox2.Text = "";
            TextBox3.Text = "";
            TextBox4.Text = "";
            TextBox5.Text = "";
            TextBox6.Text = "";
            TextBox7.Text = "";
            TextBox8.Text = "";
            TextBox9.Text = "";
            TextBox10.Text = "";
            TextBox11.Text = "";
            TextBox12.Text = "";
            TextBox13.Text = "";
            TextBox14.Text = "";
            TextBox21.Text = "";
            TextBox22.Text = "";
            TextBox23.Text = "";
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "";
            DropDownList2.SelectedValue = "";
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried writing the query with values and without it still isn't working.
I have tried checking my database to see if rows are added i have tried removing the semi-colon from the select statement its still not working.
[this is the image of the columns of my bill table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lFag.png)

Comment: Have you stepped through it with the debugger to ensure it definitely runs the insert line, and that it definitely doesn't drop into the catch block?

Comment: Im sorry can you help me with how to do that. @ADyson

Comment: You can find it online already in many places e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

Comment: I have tried debugging it with all the options mentioned it doesn't really work as when i click on debug it takes me to my page and no error is showed in the code when i use step over or step into.

Comment: `cid='" + TextBox8.Text.Trim() + "';)` should be `cid=@cid)` Don't concatenate strings in SQL like that.

Comment: I did do those changes but its still not working. I changes it in every select statement.

Comment: And you've checked in the database itself (not just in your gridview) to be sure that no new rows are added? It doesn't make sense that you get no errors but it also inserts no rows. Something doesn't add up.

Comment: P.s. cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() will return the number of rows it affected. You should check that value, if it's working it should return 1

Comment: my bill table contains 19 columns and i have cross checked the datatypes and limits everything is inside the limit and when i checked in the database no new row was added.

Comment: If no row was added then it must be failing somehow. Either the ExecuteNonQuery line of code isn't being executed at all, or it's throwing an exception. I think you need to try to debug it again more thoroughly. When you use the debugger, make sure you put a breakpoint on the line inside the Catch block, otherwise it won't stop there.

Comment: Set up SQL profiler and catch a query after it is created and sent from your application to the database engine, once you have the query text try running it directly in the SQL Server Management Studio, there you should see if it is throwing any error.
I see these are non-null columns, are you sure non of the subqueries used is returning a null?

Answer (score 0):

i think  you have a problem with sql st, you can not use param like you did,
try this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into bill (GRNo,Date,from,to,crid,crname,cid,cname,package," +"description,HSNcode,privatemark,invoiceno,value,truckid,paymentmode,actual,charged,amount)" + " (@GRNo,@Date,@from,@to,(select crid from Consignor where crid=@crid;)," +"(select crname from Consignor where crname=@crname;)," +"(select cid from Consignee where cid=@cid;)," +"(select cname from Consignee where cname=@cname;),@package,@description,@HSNcode,@privatemark," + "@invoiceno,@value,@paymentmode,@actual,@charged,@amount);", con);
```

Comment: i had written the same code before as well but it too didnt work. can you pls help me by checking what else might have caused this.

Comment: I have edited the code try to create class for sql connection and operation so that you can reuse it

Comment: should i write the code inside this code you have provided? Im so sorry i didn't get what i am expected to do here.

Comment: using (DataClass oDC = new DataClass(<CON. STRING>, true))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Add parameters                       
                       //like
                        oDC.Parameters.Add("@GRNo", TextBox1...);
                       
                        // call method
                        int intX = oDC.ExecuteSPNonQuery("<STORE PROC NAME>");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                       //...
                    }
                }